# How to add a geom_point() with observation data to tidygam.plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mgcv

Following the ([tidygam vignette 'get started'](https://stefanocoretta.github.io/tidygam/articles/get-started.html#plot-predicted-values)) , I can plot a gam model in a `ggplot` style. Increasing the `length_out` in the `predict_gam()` makes the plot look oke. How do I delete from the plot the points that were predicted and used for the plot? How can I add the original data to the plot, like the (base) plot has from `mgcv.plot()` ?

Reproducible example (as in the vignette):

```
library(tidygam)
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data("gest")

gs <- gam(
  count ~ s(months, k = 3),
  data = gest,
  family = poisson
)

# this plot is oke, but with points I do not want
# and without the original points
predict_gam(gs,
            tran_fun = exp,
            length_out = 100) %>%
  plot(series = "months")

# this gives error: ! Column `groupings` not found in `.data`.
predict_gam(gs,
            tran_fun = exp,
            length_out = 100) %>%
  plot(series = "months") +
  geom_point(data = gest)
```

I am now building my own plot with geom_ribbon(), but maybe adding on the the plot function of tidygam is the better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
library(tidygam)
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data("gest")

gs <- gam(
  count ~ s(months, k = 3),
  data = gest,
  family = poisson
)

pred <- predict_gam(gs,
            tran_fun = exp,
            length_out = 100)

# without initial points
plot0 <-
  ggplot(pred, aes(months)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci), fill = "grey10", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = count))
  
# with initial points
plot1 <-
  plot0 +
  geom_point(data = gest, aes(x = months, y = count))
    
# transform y-axis
library(scales)
plot2 <- plot1 +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = modulus_trans(-0.2))

# group plots
library(patchwork)
plot3 <- plot0 | plot1 | plot2
plot3
```

[image]